# Ruby/Rails - Convert Date/Time back into Natural Language (2011-02-17 => February 17th, 2011)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm aware of Chronic, the Natural Language Parser for converting language into database calculating format, but I'm wondering how I can convert that data back into something humans can understand easily.

For example:

```
Chronic.parse('today') => 2011-02-17 17:30:00 -0500
```

So is there a way to take "2011-02-18 20:00:00 "  and represent it as " Friday, February 18th, 2011 at 10pm "??

Essentially the reverse of Chronic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at strftime, this is a link to [it's implementation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392) for the Time class.

With it you should be able to get the date to do anything you want :-)

```
>> Time.now.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y at %l%p")
=> "Thursday, February 17, 2011 at  5PM"
```

Comment: Recommended link (for understanding all the possible date vars) http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

Answer (score 3):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s

If you wanted to do the current date and time, just do:

```
Time.current.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)
```

to get:

```
February 17th, 2011 12:16
```

If you want to write your own formatting the api shows how you can do that in that link. Here's a list of the available formats:

```
%a  weekday name.
%A  weekday name (full).
%b  month name.
%B  month name (full).
%c  date and time (locale)
%d  day of month [01,31].
%H  hour [00,23].
%I  hour [01,12].
%j  day of year [001,366].
%m  month [01,12].
%M  minute [00,59].
%p  AM or PM
%S  Second [00,61]
%U  week of year (Sunday)[00,53].
w  weekday [0(Sunday),6].
W  week of year (Monday)[00,53].
x  date (locale).
%X  time (locale).
%y  year [00,99].
%Y  year [2000].
%Z  timezone name.
```

The only reason I recommend to_formatted_s over strftime is because with a good config/initializers/time_formats.rb, you can keep your views DRYer.

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised there wasn't a "reverse of Chronic" gem, so I wrote one. It will work on your ActiveRecord objects.

Just gem install and call the 'pretty' method on your created_at field, or any other field with a class of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.

https://github.com/brettshollenberger/hublot

Comment: This already exists in Rails. Look at `initializers/date_time_formats.rb` - those specify formats you can pass to `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#to_s`. See [Time#to_formatted_s](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s). For relative times, there are the `time_ago_in_words` helpers.

Comment: In my opinion, Distance of Time in Words & Time Ago in Words provide a useful short-term solution, but not a useful long-term solution. 

"5 months ago" or "2 years ago" are not useful helpers for your users. The defaults set on Hublot anticipate that helpers like "Last Monday" are about the farthest back users will want to think about time without it being fully qualified. In my opinion, it's a better ux.

As a dev, I also tried to anticipate the way devs use model data, and added the helper directly to the fields where DOTIW & TAIW are most used in Rails apps.