# Relative dates in ruby / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know there is `distance_of_time_in_words` and gems like https://github.com/radar/dotiw and even https://github.com/brettshollenberger/hublot but they seem to lack some basic support for dates only.  For example I am posting this on Friday Oct 16, 2015.  I am looking for something like:

```
better_dates("2015-10-16") = "Today"
better_dates("2015-10-17") = "Tomorrow"
better_dates("2015-10-15") = "Yesterday"
better_dates("2015-10-14") = "Last Wednesday"
better_dates("2015-10-18") = "This Sunday"
better_dates("2015-10-23") = "Next Friday"
better_dates("2015-10-30") = "2 weeks from now"
```

I may have to roll my own helper here but I figured that this had to exist already.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, contribute it to one of the gems you mentioned. Then we all win :)

Comment: I might give it a shot but that may be beyond my skill level :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like as of right now you creating a custom module might be your best option according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779244/ruby-rails-converting-datetime-to-natural-language-e-g-3-23-2012-to-this-fri) (3 years old). It also looks like this [hublot](https://github.com/brettshollenberger/hublot/blob/master/test/dummy/spec/models/comment_spec.rb) gem does some of what you need. Maybe you could fork it to give you all extra functionality.

Comment: No. Chronic does the opposite thing. For example , It can parse `Today` to `2015-10-16` but can't parse `2015-10-16` to `Today`, which is required by @Dan.

Comment: @mainframer Ok I didn't understand the question correctly.

Comment: I was going to say something like a reverse chronic but forgot.